# Check if item in list contains a number

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, integer

I've been trying to iterate over a list in order to find the first item which contains a number.
I came across `any()` which doesn't seem to be able to 'search' for a number within an item of a list.

If I take for instance the following list:

```
["Hello", "World(2)", "Bye 3"]
```

The first item in the list which contains a number is on position 1 [World(2)].

Whether some of the following items after the first occurrence 'carry' a number is not relevant.

I started with the following:

```
list1 = ["Hello", "World(2)", "Bye 3"]

for x in list1:
     if x is.digit():        #this method doesn't work because it's only true when the whole item contains numbers.
       x = first_item_where_a_number_appears
```

It would be nice if someone could give a hint to the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the things in your list are strings, the following should work:

```
list1 = ['Hello', 'World(2)', 'Bye 3']

# For each string in the list
for s in list1:
    # If any of the characters in the string are digits:
    if any(c.isdigit() for c in s):
        # Print the string and stop searching the list.
        print(s)
        break
```

**Output:**

```
World(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution (`lst` is your list of strings):

```
idx = next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if any(c.isdigit() for c in x)),  -1)
```

`idx` will be the index of the first element containing a digit or `-1` if such an element does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have some good answers already but here's another one:

```
list1 = ['Hello', 'World(2)', 'Bye 3']
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

for x in list1:
     if any(a in x for a in numbers):
        print(x)
        break
```

```
World(2)
```